# Use more than one file in a Go program

Tags: import, go, package

I wish to learn how to logically split my code in a Go package into multiple files, and crucially, the syntax necessary to use that split/separate file in another file of the same package.

I have created a go project in this form

```
-test
    -bin
    -pkg
    -src
        -main
            main.go
            test.go
```

and attempted to run `go build main` and `go build main.go test.go`, but I have always got an error.

test.go contains only this code

```
package main
import "fmt"
func do(b string) {
    fmt.Println(b)
}
```

I want to be able to call `do("x")` in main.go.
Right now all that is in main.go is

```
package main
func main() {
    test.do("x")
}
```

I do not know what to do to get this to work.  Many answers seem to suggest moving test.go into a directory "test".  I am hoping Go does not require me to make a directory for every piece of code I write, but maybe I would be "fighting the system".  Many answers have pointed me to a website telling me to make the above directory structure, and to use `go install` to compile my binaries, but that does not work.

I just want to know how to use functions in package/x.go inside package/y.go, even if they are in the same package.  There has to be a way to do this, otherwise I will have either a bunch of unnecessary packages or hard to understand monolithic files.

I know there are many similar questions, but in my searching I haven't been able to find an actual example of the code in two files in the same package that reference each other.

Comment: You can just run "go build" as well - no need to specify the files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`test.go` has to be in the same package if is in the same directory. the package is thus `main` for both of the files and being in the same package you can just call `do("x")` .

Additionally you can build the entire package like this without specifying the single files.

```
export GOPATH="<path to>/test"

go build main
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
do
```

instead of:

```
test.do
```